# Emulator camera crashes when adding crop request

Tags: android, camera, crop

I'm calling the camera for taking pictures using the following method:

```
private void callExternalAppForImage() {
    mImageTakenUri = getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageTakenUri);
    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    intent.putExtra("scale", "false");
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    intent.putExtra("outputX", CONSTS_IMAGE_PARAMS.FULL_SIZE_SIDE);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", CONSTS_IMAGE_PARAMS.FULL_SIZE_SIDE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_IMAGE);
}
```

This comes with a rectangular border for cropping part of the image after shooting.

This works well on Samsung Galaxy 2, but when I try to run it in the Emulator then I don't get the cropping box after shooting (I can live with that) but the return code is 0 instead of Activity.RESULT_OK (=-1). Also, I get the message "Unfortunately, camera has stopped" in the Emulator.

I have two questions:
1. Does the crop function is not built in the camera intent? (note that I didn't use the com.android.camera.action.CROP intent)
2. Any idea why does it crash?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Emulator doesnt have a camera, are you using any 3rd party emulator ? whats the error you get when you run it

Answer (score 0):

> Does the crop function is not built in the camera intent?

There are well over a million apps on the Play Store. Hundreds of these are camera apps that might respond to `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. This is in addition to the dozens, if not hundreds, of camera apps that come pre-installed on Android devices.

None are required to respond to random extras that you decide to put on the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`. In particular, none are required to implement any sort of cropping capability.

If you wish to offer image cropping to your users, write it yourself, or use an image cropping library.

> Any idea why does it crash?

It has a bug, presumably.